# laravel xmlwriter not found

Tags: php, laravel, xmlwriter

I installed XmlWriter with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
sudo service apache2 restart
```

In Laravel 5.4 under App\Helpers I have XMLGenerator.php and the following command:

```
$writer = new XmlWriter();
$writer->openMemory();
....
```

I get the error:

> FatalErrorException in XMLGenerator.php line 90: Class 'App\Helpers\XmlWriter' not found

I don't understand how can i include the `XmlWriter`.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
```

Caps n' stuff.

Comment: I tried but it gives Class 'App\Helpers\XMLWriter' not found

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? It should be bundled with PHP since version 5.1.2. And, for the worst question, have you tried just restarting your machine?

Answer (score 0):

try installing xmlwriter php extension.

```
sudo apt-get install php-xmlwriter
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install php7-xmlwriter
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running ubuntu 22.04 on my hosting cloud server and I managed to get around this eror which occured when exporting sensor data into excel file format by installing XML package as:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml

sudo snap install xmlstarlet
```

and then restarting the nginx server as

```
sudo systemctrl restart nginx.service
```